# Route Globbing with parameters containing slashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
 match '/main/*params', to: 'main#parse', :constraints => {:url => /.*/}, as: 'parser',   via: 'get'
```

`params` will be called with `/p1/p2/p3/p4/`.

How do I change the route definition to be able to leave out one parameter `/p1//p3/p4/`
and still have params contain the parameter as it was entered (`/p1//p3/p4/`). Right now params = `p1/p3/p4/` with one of the forward slashes removed.

**Controller:**

```
def parse
  p = params[:params].split("/")
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your 'generic' route:

```
/.*/
```

This should match not only /p1/p2/p3/p4 but any number of parameters

You could try to declare a route BEFORE your generic one, with the specific number of parameters you want:

```
/:parameter1/:parameter2/:parameter3
```

This way, /p1/p2/p4 would match the second route and leave before matching the generic route. Similarly, /p1/p2/p3/p4 would skip the 3 parameters route but fall into the generic route.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this. Imagine the number routes needed to account for each permutation of empty parameters. This is why I wanted to define one route to account for any possibility and then parse the slashes in my controller.

Comment: I see. Can you provide the controller code that handles the parameters? That's where you will need to change. After I see that I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I added the action to my question. However, the params arrive at the controller with the parameter that was omitted removed. So '//' becomes '/'